# Hudson job unable to authenticate svn credentials

Tags: svn, hudson

I'm configuring a Hudson job to use subversion repository (installed the Hudson Subversion Plug-in 2.3.8-h-1), however Hudson is unable to authenticate:

```
Unable to access https://user/svn/myRepository : svn: E200015: No Credentials to try. Authentication failed. (show details)
(Maybe you need to enter credential?)
```

Hudson is running on my local Windows PC and the service is logging in as it's own windows user with admin rights.
The SVN server is set-up to use windows credentials.

If I click on the link to enter credentials it takes me to a page to enter Subversion Authentication with a few different methods (username/password, SSH public key, HTTPS client certificate).
I choose username/password, enter the windows credentials, click OK and Hudson returns:

```
Authentication was successful. Information is stored in Hudson now.
```

Go back to the job configuration and Hudson is still unable to authenticate, giving the same error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I run into similar issues and don't know the reason.

However, a solution to solve the issue is to:

1. Use TortoiseSVN or other SVN client to browse the SVN repo.
2. Then, try again.

On my machine (Windows7 + Hudson service + VisualSVN server + TortoiseSVN), it works.

Comment: I actually switched to Jenkins and had no issues with the exact same setup as I did on Hudson.